# Dynamically find model objects in Django and update page with its data

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, dynamic

I am stuck with a thing that I want to implement on my Django website. I want to have several inputs on a page where the user can select IDs of the objects from the database, and after they click on a button, the info about those objects need to be shown on the same page underneath. How do I do that properly with Django views and Model objects? Can I have multiple views or nested views in Django on a webpage? It wouldn't be much of an issue to send this data to a new page with another view, however, this has to be on the same page. Can anybody show me on a code example how this has to be done?